# segmenting a dataframe by matching a portion of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to select only the predominant part of a DF. For example, given

```
id_B, supportProgress
id1, A
id1, A 
id1, A
id1, A
id1, A
id1, B
id1, B
```

Output is:

```
id_B, supportProgress
id1, A
id1, A 
id1, A
id1, A
id1, A
```

I cannot apply a simple filter as I don't know what the values of supportProgress are. In another DF could be supportProgress = C,C,C,C,C,D,D and, I want only select the part corresponding to C,C,C,C,C.

My idea is to do a `df.groupby(['supportProgress'])` and select the portion that covers more than 80% of the `len(df)`.

Comment: So what do you do if no single value covers more than 80%? Select the first n values that do?

Comment: it is true that supportProgress can be nan. In that case it is ok to return the input df. and in case there is no single value that covers more than 80%, it is OK to return the most predominant one.

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you for the support. I am checking all your answers and I came back to each of you very shortly.

Comment: I tried all and, the one that produced the expected result is the one from Jezrael. Thank you very much for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) first:

```
a = df['supportProgress'].value_counts(normalize=True)
print (a)
A    0.714286
B    0.285714
Name: supportProgress, dtype: float64

#get all values by conditions
b = a.index[a > .8]
#if return no value, get all values
b = a.index if b.empty else b
print (b)
Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object')

#last filter
df = df[df['supportProgress'].isin(b)]
print (df)
  id_B supportProgress
0  id1               A
1  id1               A
2  id1               A
3  id1               A
4  id1               A
5  id1               B
6  id1               B
```

Comment: Glad can help ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the 80% but to get data for most frequent `supportProgress` you can use this:

```
df[df['supportProgress'] == df['supportProgress'].value_counts().index[0]]
```